# Why copying to flash drive takes time after copied-size matches the file size?

Tags: gnome-terminal

I use UBUNTU GNOME OS.
I feel like taking much time to copy large files to my usb. It takes few minutes after copied-size matches the file size. Please see the message for eg, "Copying 500MB of 500MB - 0 seconds left" ; After the message there is a pause for few minutes, which is not found in WINDOWS OS.
I don't understand why it pause there. Can I fix this..? 
Please help to fix.. if possibe.... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu enables Write Caching for USB media by default, Windows does not (at least in XP and 7).

When using Write Chaching, your files are written to a buffer, which is then gradually written to the USB drive. If the whole file has been written to the buffer, the dialog will tell you that it has finished copying, while the OS is still busy moving the files from the buffer to the flash drive.

**This is why you should always use the "safely eject" method in Ubuntu**, since there might still be files in the buffer that are lost if you just unplug the flash drive.

I do not recommend disabling this feature (although you [can](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/01/disable-disk-caching-prevent-data-loss/)) because it will greatly increase the wear of your flash drives (See [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/linux.kernel/vJ218uhISIg/XuEKbBmRFY0J)  for the reason why this is a bad idea).

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the data is initially copied to the buffer (which is a fast process as it involves writing to the memory) and subsequently, the buffer is written to the external device (which is a slower process owing to the fact that the write speeds are much slower).

A good way to ensure that the disk has been written to properly before ejecting is to run the `sync` command in a terminal. The command exits once the buffer has been flushed, making it is safe to eject the device.